# Characterizing equivalence classes in the reals over multiplication by rationals

Tags: set-theory, equivalence-relations, axiom-of-choice

**Fair warning:** I'm not a mathematician. My graduate education is in physics; I've never had any formal education in abstract algebra, so you may need to explain things like I am five.

Consider the group formed by set $\mathbb Q-\{0\}$ with the binary operation $\times$ (multiplication).  This group has an action on the set of real numbers $\mathbb R$. Now consider the equivalence relation defined by that action: $$\forall x,y\in\mathbb R. \quad x\sim y \iff \text{there exists nonzero $q\in\mathbb Q$ such that $x=qy$.}$$

For example, $\frac 56 \sim \frac{11}{17}$, and $2^{1/2} \sim 2^{-1/2}$, but $2^{1/3} \nsim 2^{2/3}$. Some examples of the equivalence classes under this relation are $\{0\}$, $\mathbb Q-\{0\}$, and $\left\{q \cdot \pi \mid q \in \mathbb Q-\{0\}\right\}$.

---

My question is as follows:

**Is it possible to characterize** these equivalence classes so that a representative member can be uniquely chosen from each one?  More specifically, **I would like to construct a function** $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ such that

\begin{align}
\forall x\in\mathbb R. &\quad x \sim f(x)\\
\forall x,y\in\mathbb R. &\quad x \sim y \iff f(x)=f(y)
\end{align}
If such a function cannot be constructed, **how can this be proven?**

Such a function, if one exists, would allow me to unify an equation that popped up in my research with several others. However, the existence of such a function seems untenable, because in all of those other cases, *there were always additional constraints beyond $x\in\mathbb R$* which made picking a representative member straightforward.

---

**I found [this existing question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1638125/quotient-space-of-the-reals-by-the-rationals)** but

1. nearly every word in it flies miles over my head, and
2. from what I *can* decipher, it sounds like the question is about *addition* by rationals. (perhaps all the arguments work out the same; but I cannot tell this due to (1.)!)

---

**Update:** I seek a **constructive** example; something where there is a potentially useful mathematical property which distinguishes the canonical representatives from the rest of the reals. (while a choice function does distinguish them (with regard to fixed points) it isn't particularly *useful*)

Based on the responses so far I gather that one cannot exist; the trouble then is to prove it.

Comment: The question you linked is unrelared. Such a function exists if you assume the Axiom of choice (and you could find something weaker than AC that also works). It's kind of like if you look at $\Bbb R$ as a $\Bbb Q$-vector space: you'll have a hard time finding a basis but the Axiom of choice gives you one.

Comment: Does the following (implicit) description of such a function $f$ meet your criterion of "construction"? For any $x\in{\mathbb{R}}$, choose a representative $q_{[x]}$ of the equivalence class $[x]$ (this is possible by the axiom of choice) and define $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ by $f(x)=q_{[x]}$.

Comment: Such a function is ensured by the Axiom of Choice, however I think that a constructive example cannot be found. This is because such a function would not be Lebesgue measurable.

Comment: @Crostul I am not familiar with the concept of Lebesgue measurability, can you expand on this?

Comment: @ExpHP Well, I could explain to you all the details, but I think that these would be too technical for a physicist. I suggest you to look at  [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_measure) , [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_set) , and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solovay_model). In practice, your requested function has similar properties with the Vitali set (second link), which is non-measurable. Now, the existence of non-measurable sets cannot be proved in a constructive way, since there is some model in which every set is measurable and the Axiom of Choice fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The axiom of choice is indeed necessary for this. Specifically:

> It is consistent with ZF (= set theory without choice) that there is no *transversal* of $\sim$ (that is, no set of reals containing exactly one element of each $\sim$-class).

Note that since $\{f(x): x\in\mathbb{R}\}$ would be a transversal of $\sim$, this rules out the possibility of "explicitly" constructing such an $f$.

The proof of course uses forcing and symmetric submodels, so it's a mouthful and I'm not going to give the proof here. But Cohen's original model of $ZF+\neg AC$ is a model in which this is true. See Jech's book on the axiom of choice for details on symmetric submodels, and how this kind of argument goes.

Answer (score 5):

The function you're trying to create is exactly the kind of thing that the [axiom of choice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_choice#Examples) is made for.

Note that there is an (uncountable) collection of (disjoint) equivalence classes whose union is $\Bbb R$. We may denote the collection of these equivalence classes as $\mathcal C = \{S_i : i \in I\}$ (where $I$ is some indexing set).  The axiom of choice allows us to say the following:

> There exists a function $f: \mathcal C \to \Bbb R$ such that for each $i \in I$, $f(S_i) \in S_i$.

Note that the axiom of choice is somewhat contentious.  In particular, there is a consistent, reasonable way of doing mathematics in which we disallow the construction of such sets, and it is impossible to construct (i.e. prove that an example exists) such a function within the confines of the [Zermelo-Fraenkel axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory).

I'm not quite sure how one would prove that no explicit example $f$ exists here, but I am fairly confident it can be done.  Hopefully this puts you on the right track.

---

Another point worth considering: it is possible to consider this group via addition.  Notably, if we define 
$$
L_{\Bbb Q} = \{\log(q):q \in \Bbb Q_+\}
$$
We can consider the quotient $G = (\mathbb{R},+)/L_{\Bbb Q}$.  The map
$$
\phi:G \to (\Bbb R, \cdot)/(\Bbb Q \setminus \{0\})\\
\phi([r]) = [\exp(r)]
$$
is an injective homomorphism.  Here, $[x]$ denotes the equivalence class of $x$.

Comment: I am a bit lost on the second point;  since it is taking a set as an argument, I gather that $\exp$ here is not the typical $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ function we all know and love?

Comment: I think it a bit of an exaggeration nowadays to say that $\mathsf{AC}$ is somewhat contentious. I suspect that it’s not just a minority, but a rather small minority of working mathematicians who have problems with it.

Comment: @ExpHP: No, $\exp$ is the usual $x\mapsto e^x$, assuming that the logs in question are natural logs. If they’re logs to some other base $b$, then $\exp(r)$ should be interpreted as $b^r$.

Comment: Yeah, looks like that was poor reading on my part; I mentally swapped $r$ and $[r]$ in the last equation

Comment: For the record, I did mean natural logs and $e^x$.  Thanks Brian for stepping in there.